# Running Mocha tests on Bamboo

Tags: mocha.js, bamboo

I'm trying to run a test suite for Node.js project in Bamboo, but Bamboo is not recognizing my test suite

This is the structure of the Nodej.js project:

```
Project
    app
        controller
        model
        routes
        services
    node_modules
    test
        controller
            test1.js
            //more tests
        model
            test1.js
            //more tests
        routes
            test1.js
            //more tests
        services
            test1.js
            //more tests
    package.json
    //other files
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
      //dependencies  
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.0",
    "growl": "^1.8.1",
    "grunt-generate": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "mocha-bamboo-reporter": "*",
    "sinon": "^2.3.8",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "forever-start": "forever start server.js -l -o -e",
    "bamboo": "node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -R mocha-bamboo-reporter"
  }
}
```

When I run tests locally in my computer, I just go to my application directory, open the console, write *mocha --recursive --reporter min* and execute. Then, all my tests run perfectly, but I had to install mocha globally before in my computer.

How can I do this in Bamboo? I tried to rearrange my tests so that they're not organized by folders and Bamboo is able to recognize them and run them, but I prefer to keep them in separate folders.

And by the way, I followed the Atlassian's tutorial (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboocloud/getting-started-with-node-js-and-bamboo-737183843.html)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done mocha tests on bamboo, so take this suggestion with big grain of salt.  It might be just a restriction of the canned mocha test runner packaged with bamboo.  What if instead of using the mocha test runner bamboo task, you tried a vanilla script task in its place, and just execute the same command you run on your local box in that script.

If that works, and produces a test result file, you could then add a mocha test results parser task after that shell task.

Also if you're going to be using mocha with a lot of projects, you could install it globally on the bamboo server - may cut down some execution time.